# Segmentation fault error in my code for level order traversal

Tags: tree, segmentation-fault

```
void printLevelOrder(struct node* root)
{
  int rear, front;
  struct node **queue = createQueue(&front, &rear);  
  struct node *temp_node = root; 

  while(temp_node)
  {
    printf("%d ", temp_node->data);

    /*Enqueue left child */
    if(temp_node->left->left)
      enQueue(queue, &rear, temp_node->left->left);

    /*Enqueue right child */
    if(temp_node->left->right)
      enQueue(queue, &rear, temp_node->left->right);

      if(temp_node->right->left)
      enQueue(queue, &rear, temp_node->right->left);

    /*Enqueue right child */
    if(temp_node->right->right)
      enQueue(queue, &rear, temp_node->right->right);

    /*Dequeue node and make it temp_node*/
    temp_node = deQueue(queue, &front);
  }
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault error in the above code. I am using level order traversal to print the alternate level in a tree.

Please help.The logic seems to be correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are skipping some levels through your traversal. In your example, `if(temp_node->left->left)` will generate segmentation fault error if `temp_node->left` doesn't exist. As such, for each iteration, you should check `if(temp_node->left)` and `if(temp_node->right)` instead.

For a detailed implementation, you can refer to [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/).